# How to use SendButton of facebook on android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use this code snippet from [developer.facebook.com](http://developer.facebook.com) to send message to facebook friends using messenger.

```
SendButton sendButton = (SendButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_send_button);
sendButton.setShareContent(shareContent);
sendButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() 
{ ... });
```

Here I am facing some problems:

(1) Which button of facebook layout we need to choose in `fb_send_button` ?

(2) I tried to build shareContent object like this :

```
ShareContent shareContent = new  ShareContent.Builder().setContentUrl(Uri.parse("someurl")).setRef("someContent").build();
```

but it gives me error that `"Builder is abstract; cannot be instantiated"`. So how to use to ShareContent to create a content to send using SendButton?

Answer (score 0):

here how i made it work, bear in mind, your phone **needs** to have the app mesenger installed otherwise the button will remain grey

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.SendButton
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="I write to my friends"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

--

```
import com.facebook.share.widget.SendButton;
SendButton sendButton = (SendButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook);

ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Hello")
            .setContentDescription("How are you? here's a link")
            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/596777148435705856/tsE4inUQ.jpg"))
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/596777148435705856/tsE4inUQ.jpg"))
            .build();

sendButton.setShareContent(linkContent);
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //do what you want on click if needed, its usually not

        }
    });
```